# JSON-LD | Multiple Schemas Per Page | What is the best way to structure a website?

Tags: seo, schema, json-ld, rich-snippets

Please excuse me, I am a noob and schemas are something new to me and I would really appreciate your expert advice guys! Thanks in advance! :)

**To keep it short, I combined these 3 relevant question as part of one global question:**

1. What is better? To use separate schemas or multiple nested schemas per web page?
2. How many schemas can be used per page? Is there a recommended minimum and maximum?
3. Lastly, what would the schema structure of a i.e 5 page website look like?

*I've answered all these questions in a short summary below, followed by the schemas I've used.*

**My curreny interpretation:**

a. You can nest multiple schemas per page, but keeping them separate allows for a better use of `@id`?

b. You can use as many schemas per page as you wish without penalty, taken you use `@graph` but then each separate web page needs to be defined separately. Is this practical?

c. You can, and should use multiple schemas per page, in separate scripts so as not to duplicate the same information via: `about`, `provider`, or `@type`, particularly when you are using multiple schema types: `Organization`, `Corporation` and/or `LocalBusiness`?

d. The structure/hierarchy we are currently implementing is as follows:

i. Home Page Schema Types: `Website`, `Webpage`, `Breadcrumb` and `FAQPage`.

ii. About Page Schema Types: `Webpage`, `Organization` and `Local Business`.

iii. Service Page Schema Types: `Webpage`, `Service`, `OfferCatalog`, `Breadcrumb` and `FAQPage`.

iv. Individual Service Page Schema Types: `Webpage`, `Service`, `OfferCatalog`, `Breadcrumb` and `FAQPage`.

v. Contact Page Schema Types: `Webpage` and `ContactPage`.

**Current Implementation Home Page (Website Schema)**

*I might have overdone it, from what I understand it is better to include less information and more reference with* `@id`

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "Website",
"name": "ABC Company",
"image": "https://www.abccompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"url": "https://www.abccompany.com",
"abstract": "The corporate website of ABC Company Ltd.",
"description": "Website of ABC Company Ltd, an information technology service management and support provider in Germany.",
"thumbnailUrl": "https://www.abccompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"about": 
        {
        "@type": 
                [
                "Organization",
                "LocalBusiness"
                ],
        "@id": "https://www.abccompany.com/about",
        "name": "ABC Company",
        "image": "https://www.abccompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
        "legalname": "ABC Company Ltd",
        "alternateName":
                [
                "ABC Corp",
                "ABC Berlin",
                "ABC"
                ],
        "address": 
                {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "addressCountry": "Germany",
                "addressLocality": "Berlin",
                "addressRegion": "Berlin Municipality",
                "postalCode": "30242",
                "streetAddress": "Zigrid Abc Street, Office 521"        
                },
        "pricerange": "€€ - €€€€",
        "telephone": "99 540 010"
        },
"sameAs": 
        [
        "https://www.facebook.com/abccompany",
        "https://twitter.com/abccompany",
        "https://www.instagram.com/abccompany/",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/abccompany"
        ],
"spatialCoverage": 
        [
        "United Kingdom",
        "Germany",
        "Greece",
        "Switzerland",
        "United Arab Emirates",
        "Italy"
        ]
}
```

*Below is a simplified version of the Website Schema for the Home Page*

```
{
        "@type": "Website",
        "name": "ABC Company Website",
        "url": "https://www.abccompany.com",
        "description": "Website of ABC Company Ltd, an information technology service management and support provider in Germany.",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://www.abccompany.com/wpcontent/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
        "about": 
                {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "ABC Company",
                "@id": "https://www.abccompany.com/about"
                },
        "potentialAction": 
                {
                "@type": "SearchAction",
                "target": "{search_term_string}",
                "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
                }
        }
```

**Current Implementation Home Page (Organization Schema)**

*Thinking of moving this Schema to the about page. Any suggestions?*

```
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@id": "https://www.abccompany.com/about",
"@type": "Organization",
"name": "ABC Company",
"alternateName": 
        [
        "ABC Berlin",
        "ABC"
        ],
        "knowsAbout":
                [
                "Information Technology Consulting",
                "Information Technology Support",
                "Information Technology Development",
                "Managed Information Technology",
                "API Integration"
                ],
"url": "https://www.abccompany.com",
"logo": "https://www.abccompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"sameAs": 
        [
        "https://www.facebook.com/abccompany",
        "https://twitter.com/abccompany",
        "https://www.instagram.com/abccompany",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/abccompany"
        ],
"numberofEmployees": "~10",
"owns": 
        [
        {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "ABC Company 2",
        "url": "https://abccompany2.com/",
        "logo": "https://abccompany2.png",
        "description": "Online ticketing platform.",
        "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/abccompany2"
        },
        {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "ABC Company 3",
        "url": "https://abccompany3.eu/en/",
        "logo": "https://abccompany3.eu/en.png",
        "description": "Laptop and phone repair service.",
        "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/abccompany3"            
        }
        ],
"contactPoint": 
        {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "telephone": "+357-99-550-010",
        "contactType": "Contact",
        "email": "contact@abccompany.com",
        "areaServed": 
                [
                "United Kingdom",
                "Germany",
                "Greece",
                "Switzerland",
                "United Arab Emirates",
                "Italy"
                ],
        "availableLanguage": 
                [
                "English",  
                "German"
                ]
        }
}
```

**Current Implementation Home Page (Local Business Schema)**

*As with the Organization schema, I am thinking of moving it to the about page and link `@id`. Additionally, Organization and Local Business Schemas tend to clash, is this because of duplicate information?*

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "LocalBusiness",
"name": "ABC Company",
"legalname": "ABC Company Ltd",
"image": "https://www.abccompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"@id": "https://www.abccompany.com/about",
"url": "https://www.abccompany.com",
"logo": "https://www.abccompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"hasMap": "https://www.google.com/maps/place/ABCCOMPANY+-+IT+Services+%26+Solutions+in+Cyprus/@44.6799323,65.0355366,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x4507a4904ebbe662?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOnOKdy_bxAhWQsRQKHY9WD5kQ_BIwD3oECEMQBQ",
"address": 
        {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "Germany",
        "addressLocality": "Berlin",
        "addressRegion": "Berlin Municipality",
        "postalCode": "3022",
        "streetAddress": "Mitgard Street 302"       
        },
"description": "ABC Company Ltd is a managed information technology services provider in Germany.",
"disambiguatingDescription": "ABC Company is an information technology support and development company.",
"sameAs":
        [
        "https://www.facebook.com/abccompany",
        "https://twitter.com/abccompany",
        "https://www.instagram.com/abccompany",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/company/abccompany"
        ],
"pricerange": "€€€ - €€€€€",
"email": "mailto:contact@abccompany.com",
"telephone": "99 520 010",
"geo":
        {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": "66.6799323",
        "longitude": "55.0355366"
        },
"areaServed": 
        [
        {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": "United Kingdom",
        "sameAs": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_(disambiguation)"   
        },
        {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": "Germany",
        "sameAs": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany_(disambiguation)"
        },
        {"@type": "Country",
        "name": "Greece",
        "sameAs": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greece_(disambiguation)"
        },
        {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": "Switzerland",
        "sameAs": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland_(disambiguation)"
        },
        {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": "United Arab Emirates",
        "sameAs": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAE_(disambiguation)"
        },
        {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": "Italy",
        "sameAs": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy_(disambiguation)"
        }
        ],
"openingHoursSpecification": 
        [
        {
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "dayOfWeek": 
                [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday"
                ],
        "opens": "09:00",
        "closes": "19:00"
        },
        {
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
        "opens": "11:00",
        "closes": "14:00"
        }
        ],
"aggregateRating":
        {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "reviewCount": "5"
        },
"review":
        [
        {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": 
                {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "BBB Company Ltd"
                },
        "datePublished": "2020",
        "description": "Developed a great website.",
        "reviewRating":
                {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "5"
                }
        },
        {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": 
                {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Anderson Silva"
                },
        "datePublished": "2018",
        "reviewRating":
                {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "5"
                }
        },
        {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": 
                {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "NFS Ltd"
                },
        "datePublished": "2017",
        "reviewRating":
                {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "5"
                }
        },
        {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": 
                {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "Premiere Showroom"
                },
        "datePublished": "2020",
        "reviewRating":
                {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "5"
                }
        },
        {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": 
                {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Benzon Bez"
                },
        "datePublished": "2017",
        "reviewRating":
                {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "5"
                }
        }
        ]           
}
```

**Current Implementation Home Page (WebPage Schema)**

*This is the last schema I will share, to keep this question manageable.*

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "WebPage",
"@id": "https://www.abccompany.com",
"url": "https://www.abccompan.com",
"name": "IT Services and Solutions | ABC Company",
"description": "Home web page of ABC Company Ltd, an information technology service management and support provider in Germany.",
"disambiguatingDescription": "ABC Company Home Page",
"image": "https://www.abccompan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"thumbnailUrl": "https://www.abccompan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/company_slider.png",
"keywords": "IT Company, Information Technology Company, IT Provider",  
"typicalAgeRange": "28-60",
"about":  
        {
        "@type": "Organization", 
        "@id": "https://www.abccompan.com/about",
        "name": "ABC Company"
        },
"audience": 
        [
        {
        "@type": "BusinessAudience",
        "name": "Business owner",
        "alternateName": "Organizational Founder",
        "disambiguatingDescription": "Refers to founders, owners and or majority shareholders of a commercial enterprise.",
        "sameAs": 
                ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_founder",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_(business)",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_magnate",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tycoon_(disambiguation)",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrialist_(disambiguation)",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shareholder"
                ]
        },
        {
        "@type": "BusinessAudience",
        "name": "Entrepreneur",
        "alternateName": "Business Person",
        "disambiguatingDescription": "A business man or woman - refers to a founder, owner, investor or majority shareholder of a commercial enterprise.",
        "sameAs": 
                [
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrepreneur_(disambiguation)",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Businessperson",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investor",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediary"
                ]
        },
        {
        "@type": "BusinessAudience",
        "name": "Manager",
        "alternateName": "Supervisor",
        "disambiguatingDescription": "Refers to founders, owners and or majority shareholders of a commercial enterprise.",
        "sameAs": 
                ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manager_(disambiguation)",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_manager" 
                ]
        }
        ],
"datePublished": "2016-12-01T08:00:08+00:00",
"dateModified":"2020-01-09T18:00:00+00:00",
"inLanguage":"en-UK",
"potentialAction":
        {
        "@type": "ReadAction",
        "target": "https://www.abccompany.com"
        }
}
```

**To recap**

1. Are the schemas above correct?
2. Do we write multiple schemas per page but in separate scripts?
3. Is best practice to then link @id or duplicate references?
4. How many schemas can we populate per page?
5. Are there particular schemas for particular pages only? If so which ones?

In advance thank you all for your time and effort.
Hope we can reach some sort of consensus, since there are no viable instructions regarding this, at least that I've found.

Peace.

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: That's a lot to put into one question. But, a note on nomenclature: in JSON-LD, an entity is described by a "node object". Neither JSON-LD nor RDF really have the notion of a "schema", per-se, not withstanding the popular schema.org vocabulary. You might think that the vocabulary defines an overall schema, and there are tools to validate data against such a vocabulary.

Comment: Regarding the suitability of using embedded nodes, or multiple script blocks, these are all valid per the JSON-LD specification. You seem to be asking for SEO purposes, if Google or other parsers, will use this, which is really an SEO question, but typically they should. Can't really speak to the validity of your data, but there are various sites for testing data, for example the SDTT or Structured Data Linter.

Comment: To clarify, RDF does have RDF Schema (RDFS), but it is not really a schema in the sense of a required data shape (see SHACL or ShEx). Really, it is a way to infer information, and set minimum boundaries on what literal data can be considered valid.